# Сайт погоды через API

Tags: javascript, html, json, hosting

Сайт с определением погоды, я сделал что при входе на него берётся долгота и широта откуда зашли, на локалке работает, на хосте нет, ошибок тоже нет

Вот сайт поставленный на хост: http://local-wether.zzz.com.ua/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Plus+Jakarta+Sans&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>My Weather</title> 
</head>
<body onload="fetchTest()">
    <div class="container">
        

        <div class="weather">
            <div class="city">Some city</div>
            <section>
                <div class="firsLine">
                    <div class="Grid">
                        <img src="img/Group 16.png" alt="cloudy">
                        <div class="temperature">- -&deg;</div>
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="discription">weather</div>
                </div>

                <div class="secondLine">
                    <div class="Grid">
                        <img src="img/Group 35.svg" alt="" class="icon">
                        <img src="img/cloud.svg" alt="" class="icon">
                        <img src="img/Vector (1).svg" alt="" class="icon">
                    </div>
                    <div class="Grid">
                        <p class="wind">-- M/S</p>
                        <p class="clouds">-- %</p>
                        <p class="sun"></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                
            </section>
            <input type="text" class="koord" id="lat" >
        <input type="text" class="koord" id="lon" >
        <button class="button-primary" onclick="fetchTest()">Go</button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

```
function fetchTest() {

  let lat = document.getElementById('lat');
  let lon = document.getElementById('lon');
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position){
  lat = position.coords.latitude;
  lon = position.coords.longitude;
  console.log(lat);
  console.log(lon);
  

  fetch(`https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=${lat}&lon=${lon}&appid=70f3a9c2d617493de79c5fec2b5612c5`)
    .then(function(resp) {
      return resp.json()
    })
    .then(function(data) {
      console.log(data);
      document.querySelector('.city').textContent = data.name;
      document.querySelector('.temperature').innerHTML = Math.round(data.main.temp - 273) + '&deg;';
      document.querySelector('.discription').textContent = data.weather[0]['description'];
      document.querySelector('.wind').textContent = data.wind.speed + ' m/s';
      document.querySelector('.clouds').textContent = data.clouds.all + ' %';
      document.querySelector('.features li').innerHTML = data.weather[0]['icon'];
    })
    .catch(function(e) {
      console.log(e)   
    });

  })};
```

Comment: Зачем удалять такой же старый вопрос и копировать заново если он был закрыт с сылкой на инструменты, с помощью которых можно (**и нужно**) найти ошибки самому?

Comment: Потому что ошибок на пк нету, только при установке на хостинг не показывает погоду, при запросе геолокации должно спрашивать разрешение, но его не спрашивают и такая проблема только на хосте

Comment: Ну на хосте...И что? у тебя код клиентский (читай как **в браузере**)...какая тут разница хост это или на Сатурне...

Comment: Короче, я понял, как объяснить, у меня просто не запрашивает разрешение на получение геоданных ТОЛЬКО если сайт установлен на хост, НО если я открываю файлы через index.html на своём пк, то всё запрашивает, в настройках браузера моего запрещённого зайта нет.
Я уже 2 дня безуспешно пытаюсь понять в чём проблема.